# Regex expression includes extra character

Tags: c#, regex

Hope this is really easy question, but I have the following string of data see  below:

```
*frac {7frac {1} {2}&nbsp;+ 8} {frac {3} {4} +3} = 4
```

Want to return the following

```
frac {1} {2}
frac {3} {4}
```

But am getting back the following:

```
7frac {1} {2}    
{frac {3} {4}
```

The expression I've got up to now is:

```
[^\\*]frac\s{(.*?)}\s*{(.*?)}
```

How do I remove the extra start character?

Cheers

Comment: remove the match stuff before frac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use `[^\\*]` to exclude matches where the potential match is prefixed with a "*". It works, but it includes the prefix in the match. You can use a [negative lookbehind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_negative_lookbehind_assertion) (`(?<!\*)`) to accomplish the same thing without including the prefix in your match.

```
(?<![*\\])frac\s{(.*?)}\s*{(.*?)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to not include the extra bit at the start of your expression.  Do you really need the start of string?  It doesn't look like it to me.  So just use:
`frac\s{(.*?)}\s*{(.*?)}`

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the first `[^\\*]` . The expression should be only:

```
frac\s{(.*?)}\s*{(.*?)}
```

Comment: I believe the `[^\\*]` was an attempt to not match that first 'frac'.